# Relative, block level divs overlapping

Tags: css, css-position, overlap

In my website, `shop_description` and `shop_picture` are overlapping each other even though both these divs are `position:relative` and `display:block`. They also don't have any floats.

*Just for context, the divs are also in this container div `shop_bar`*.

My question is, why are they over-lappping? I don't want them to overlap.

```
#shop_description { 
    max-width:70%;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;  
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin: 3% auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: block;
    border:1px solid red
}

#shop_picture {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:50px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block
    border:1px solid blue;
}

#shop_picture img{
    width:72%;
    height:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid green
}

#shop_bar {
    z-index:20;
    width:0%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow-x:none;
    overflow-y:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Screenshot of the problem. Red box is `shop_description`. Blue box is `shop_picture`. Green box is `shop_picture img`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO2yn.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing the #shop_picture down with

```
#shop_picture {
    ...
    top: 50px;
    ...
    position: relative;
    ...
```

whereas #shop_description doesn't have that much relative push down.

So, unless you have enough margin on #shop_description, or unless #shop_description is within #shop_picture markup they will overlap.

Comment: yep, I realised that. I found that margin-top is a alternative to top if you want a push while affecting nearby relative divs.

Answer (score 1):

using `top` does not respect the flow of the document.

```
.div1 {
   position:relative;
   top:10px
}

.div2 {
   position:relative;
   top:0px
}
```

**Result: apple will overlap orange**

but with `margin-top`, they won't overlap.

```
.div1 {
   position:relative;
   margin-top:10px
}

.div2 {
   position:relative;
   top:0px
}
```

**Result: apple will be pushed down 10px with orange and will not overlap.**